# In Azure datafacctory in copy data activity only top 3 parameters of linked services are shown in source settings

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Datafactory I'm using **CopyActivity** to copy data from **SQL database** to **Azure table storage**.
I'm filling up the sql connection linked service properties dynamically. So I have declared 4 properties each for server,databese,usename & password .
[image]

But when I'm using this linked service in the source of CopyActivity only top 3 parameters are showed. Is it a limitation or  an error ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried in my lab environment and noticed that if you have created a source dataset from copy data activity with parameters, initially is showing only 3 parameters under dataset properties.

But if you refresh your dataset in copy data activity it is then showing all the 4 parameters.

Or you can first create your dataset and then add copy data activity to your pipeline and select your source dataset to show all your parameters in Dataset properties.

[image]

Comment: how do I refresh the dataset in copy activity, didn't find any option for this ?

Comment: select any other dataset or nothing from the dropdown and then again select your dataset.

Comment: tq this is weird , but it worked ,

Comment: Glad it worked!